# Pick recipients like MFMailComposeViewController does?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, xamarin.ios

MFMailComposeViewController has this cool way of adding recipients. Either by picking from the address book or by autocompleting whatever the user types. Then the selected address is converted into this blue button-like thing. Backspacing deletes the blue thing/the address.

I would like to have exactly this way of recipients in my application to select some users. Does anybody know of an implementation with source available? Or has somebody a clear idea how Apple implemented it?

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself capable in translation objective-c to C# then you could always look at the Three20 library. They have implemented it in their TT Message Controller.

Comment: I find Three20 quite chaotic. I've tried to browse it a bit but cannot find which module would be the right one. Do you know the class name?

Comment: From Three20 I learned that one has to implement it from scratch. There is no built-in control. I ended up using a UIView which contains a textfield and adds custom buttons as recipients are added. A hidden textfield is used to allow "backspace" to delete a button. LayoutSubViews() is overriden to make everything look nice.

Comment: That sounds like awesome! Is it going to be in a public facing app? Looking forward to seeing it if it is