# How insert blue text tokens inside UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Is there a way to make the UITextField (or some class similar) create this blue text token natively? If not, someone knows any example code that's similar?

[image]

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247072/recreate-recipient-bubble-behaviour-in-mail-app-three20

Answer (score 4):

I've not had a chance to test it out, but this might be of interest to you:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jstokenfield

(Also, CocoaControls is a great website!)

Comment: Nice answer!  I was trying to find a good practical example of `CFStringTokenizer` to show Juliano but I think your answer is a better starting point.

Answer (score 4):

TITokenField is also a nice option:
https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField

Comment: I like this one better!