# drag text between textfield like mail app of ios 5

Tags: ios, uitextfield, drawable

I want implement drag text between textfield like mail app of ios5.

here is video link and image what i want to implement.
video link.
(just observe on 2:49 min).
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JURDFe2PNE&feature=b-vrec

image:

[image]

Comment: i am trying to to convert text into image and dragging that image .......but i think that is not good idea ........it seems like there should be some delegate method to do that...

Comment: @Virendra Please check out this link, may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247072/recreate-recipient-bubble-behaviour-in-mail-app-three20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split this into three tasks:

1. Containing the data you want into an appropriate UIView-based class/subclass
2. Handling the relevant touch events to initiate and end the drag and drop
3. Animating the move between your source and destination

You can implement these one at a time in order to develop precisely the drag and drop functionality you need.

You shouldn't need to convert your view to an image, as UIView subclasses can be animated by Core Animation. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707858/basic-drag-and-drop-in-ios) has more info on handling touch events.

Good luck!