# Monotouch: How to add/remove recipients balloons/bubbles for new message

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I want to create custom email compose dialog and I need to implement "Add contact" func. like in standard iOS apps.
I haven't found any nifty controls so it seams it should be implemented manually.
So I wonder how to draw such an elements dynamically inside of MT.D element?

UPD:
Let me show a picture from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247072/recreate-recipient-bubble-behaviour-in-mail-app-three20):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found any nifty controls so it seams it should be implemented manually.

Look at the **New-Person View Controller** in Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1). They are all available to use from MonoTouch applications.

Comment: Thanks, but I need manageable contact balloons with X button.

Comment: Not sure what you mean bu *ballons* ? Could you edit your question to add a picture that show what you're looking for ?

Comment: He's probably talking about the blue bubbles used when adding recipients to an email. You can drag them and tap to edit. As far as I know this is not exposed via public API.

Comment: Exactly! I wonder if there monotouch port of any such controls?!