# Filling an image with color

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an image and would like to fill it with color. The image is a flat bubble like the iOS 7 message app bubble. Basically, I want to use it as a shape. How can I do this?

Comment: why not color the image :)

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5304995/189804

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your question to be honest :)

If you want a picture filled with color, either fill the picture in photoshop, and then use it in your code afterwards.

Otherwise make a circle with a div :) And just use background-color: black; or whatever color you want.